# React/JSX dynamic component names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to render a component based upon a string. Essentially, I am hoping to find the JSX equivalent to JavaScript's dynamic function name ability (`parent["childMethod"]`).

So, if I have a string, such as `"<MyComponent />"`, how can I turn into JSX and render?

Comment: Why do you need to use JSX if you are already putting it into a string?

Comment: Your title and your second paragraph present different problems. If you've specifically got a *component name* in a string, as implied by your title, you can (assuming your build pipeline doesn't minify or otherwise change component names) create an *element* from it with [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement), store that element in a variable, and include the element within some JSX using curly braces. If you have the entire JSX code for an element in a string, though, like `"<MyComponent />`, you need another solution that I don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic tag name in React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-react-jsx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSX is just a nice syntax for function calls, so you need to have the actual functions to use a component. If you have an object that contains React components then you can render a component based on a string property. For example if you have an object called MyComponents (has to be uppercase for JSX) and that object has React components like `MyComponents.SomeInput = React.CreateClass(...)`. Then you can use `<MyComponents.SomeInput />` in your JSX.

Comment: i'm having the same problem but ```var ContentBlocks = {
 info  : require('./Infoblock'),
 portrait : require('./Portraitblock')
};``` and ```<ContentBlocks['info']>``` throws an error

Comment: I just checked and you're right, you can use `<ContentBlocks.info>` or alternatively do `var MyComponent = MyComponents['info'];` and `<MyComponent>` if the key isn't known when you're writing it.