# DRY jsx render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dry

I wonder if it is a better way to DRY this code, have you guys any ideas?
The props are the same, just the component change...

```
render() {
    const { input: { value, onChange }, callback, async, ...rest } = this.props;

    if (async) {
      return (
        <Select.Async
          onChange={(val) => {
            onChange(val);
            callback(val);
          }}
          value={value}
          {...rest}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <Select
        onChange={(val) => {
          onChange(val);
          callback(val);
        }}
        value={value}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: If the code is working and you want to improve it/get it reviewed, you can post it on [codereview.se]. Before you do, please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Comment: @Tushar thanks, I'll remember it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
let createElement = function(Component) {
    return (
        <Component onChange={(val) => { 
            onChange(val);
            callback(val);
            }}
            value={value}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
};
```

you can do

```
let selectAsync = createElement(Select.Async);
let select = createElement(Select);
```

You can render them in the jsx part with `{{select}} and {{selectAsync}}`

P.S.: I didnt test this directly, but did something very similar a few days ago, so this approach should work. Note that Component must start with a capital letter.