# Reactjs how to convert string to [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `menuItem` component and its props is a **Icon** component created by me and called `FontIcon`.

And in `menuItem` props you can pass a name of the icon as a string, for example: `leftIcon="face"` but you can also pass a code for the component like this: `leftIcon='<FontIcon style={{color:"red"}} className="face" />'`.

In the first case, all works perfectly, the props is passed to the variable where is code for the component:

`leftIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />;`

But this second way is not working. When the user passes all code I need to add something to this(this size value like above), at this point this adding works:

`leftIcon = _props.leftIcon.replace(/\/>$/, " size={_props.fontSize}/>");`

Here I've got `if` to check what has the user passed:

```
if (_props.leftIcon.match(/<.+\/>/)) {
    leftIcon = _props.leftIcon.replace(/\/>$/, " size={_props.fontSize}/>");
} else {
    leftIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />;
}
```

But in this second way, I'm getting a string and it doesn't work. There is no icon, but there is a string with code:

[image]

So I've consoled log this and it's what I got:

[image]

The `typeof` this first is **object** but this second one is **string**.

So what can do to make this second way works?

Answer (score 0):

If this code is in the render portion this should work;

```js
if (_props.leftIcon.match(/<.+\/>/)) {
    leftIcon = _props.leftIcon.replace(/\/>$/, " size={_props.fontSize}/>");
} else {
    leftIcon = (<FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />);
}
```

Note the parenthesis.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work because you've worked out this working part, this first `if` doesn't working because it's string.

Comment: I missed that you were passing it as a prop. In that case you need to pass the type as a prop and do the rest in menuItem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what do you mean: "pass the type as a prop".

Comment: Instead of passing the icon as a prop pass the _props.leftIcon and _props.fontSize and do the if in menuItem.

Comment: Basically it's a first way

Comment: Sometimes I don't read it through. Try with javascript template literals; leftIcon = _props.leftIcon.replace(/\/>$/, ` size=${_props.fontSize}/>`);

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to create component from string you can take a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

But I would suggest you to pass styles and / or class names and other parameters to your component rather then a string and then you could just have:

```
 return <FontIcon class={condition ? 'firstClass' : 'secondClass'} ... />;
```