# How to dynamically create and render JSX elements, defined from this.props with react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So I want to create and render a JSX element based on the 'this.props.x', where this 'this.props.x' is the state passed down from app.jsx.

I do have a workaround which works fine, but it is really ugly! Which is why I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this.

So the way i do it now, is with an if/else like so:

```
import React from 'react'

import Team from './inMenuTeam.jsx';
import News from './inMenuNews.jsx';

export default class GameArea extends React.Component{
    GameStage(page){
        if(page == 'News'){
            return <News />
        }
        else{
            return <Team />
        }
    }
    render(){
        return( 
            <div>
                {this.GameStage(this.props.newStage)}
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

What i want to do i something like this:

```
export default class GameArea extends React.Component{
    GameStage(page){
        return <page />
    }
    render(){
        return( 
            <div>
                <GameMenuLeft handleMenuClick={this.props.handleMenuClick.bind(this)} />
                {this.GameStage(this.props.newGameAreaStage)}
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Where the 'page' element is the prop beeing passed by the parent jsx file.
Above code doesn't work, but doesn't provide me with an error either, so i have a feeling that I'm close to the desired solution.

Thank you :)

(UPDATE)
Looking back at it, i realise that what i was actually looking for, was react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `page` component. A similar way to do it would be:

```
const pages = {
  News: News,
  Team: Team,
}; // this could also be shorthanded as const pages = { News, Team };

GameStage(page){
  const Page = pages[page];
  return <Page />
}
```

You can't have dynamic inline component names, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name) for more info.

Comment: This is perfect! 
Clean, easy to read, and scales really well.

Thank you Andy_D

Answer (score 1):

for more elegant code you can use a **[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**:

```js
export default class GameArea extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.props.newStage === 'News' ? <News/> : <Team/>
      } 
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: This definantly shortens the code by alot!
I will keep this syntax in mind and use it at a later instance of my project :)

Andy_D's answer is more what i'm looking for, I do however really appreciate that you took your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create React element [manually from the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html):

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>;
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null));
```