# react - render dynamic component insider render function of other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a web app using react and i have a issue.
my component get a 'exists component name' and I try to render this new component inside render function of the current component.

my current component render function

```
render(){

    let Xxx = null;
    if( this.props.onHex ){
      console.log( this.props.onHex );
      Xxx = <this.props.onHex />
    }

    return(
        <div className="myClass">
            <div className="anotherClass">
               {Xxx}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

it not works for me, the console log returns the name of the new component "Unit". when I replace the `Xxx = <this.props.onHex />` with this `Xxx = <Unit />` it works and render the Unit's render function.

it looks like react not recognise `<Unit/>` as component.
what I am doing wrong please advise.

my Unit code:

```
    export default class Unit extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
when I use `const XxxName = Unit; Xxx = <XxxName />;` it works for me but I want to be able to render the component from string ( I got this string from json ).
I guess I can create all my possible components at this situation inside a file load them into array or something and get them by string, but it's not something that can live with I have a lot of components maybe if I will some how load them from separate folder ( individual file for each component ) it will be half solution. but I still looking how to load component from string.

jsFiddle with another similar issue http://jsfiddle.net/dhjxu5oL/

UPDATE 2:
I am not found elegant way to reach my goal (I don't sure if it exists) for now I am using method for each dynamic component for hope that someone will advise me with more elegant solution. check it: [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

```
newExampleComponent() {
    return <ExampleComponent />;
}

newComponent(type) {
    return this["new" + type + "Component"]();
}
```

Comment: Is `this.props.onHex` a string or a reference of some kind?

Comment: You can't pass "component name" `<CurrentComponent onHex="Unit"/>`  and expect it to pick the component constructor you have somewhere else. You need to pass a reference to your Unit component like this `<CurrentComponent onHex={Unit}/>`

Comment: @Chris this is a string.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko why not it not sounds so bad for me, what the different between `<Unit />` and `<$unit />`, this comment actually  gave me an idea to use something like `const Xxx = window[ this.props.onHex ]()` because when I use `const Xxx = Unit;` it works.

Comment: " what the different between <Unit /> and <$unit />" no difference in this case. But if you do `<unit/>` it will be desugared to `React.createElement('unit', null)` not `React.createElement(unit, null)`. "gave me an idea to use something like const Xxx = window[ this.props.onHex ]()" this is bad idea because you are polluting global scope with your components. High chances to introduce subtle bugs caused by name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

```
let Xxx = null;
if( this.props.onHex ){
  const XxxName = this.props.onHex;
  Xxx = <XxxName />;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/janklimo/azzohvn1/4/) for example

---

UPDATE:

According to [React official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

> You cannot use a general expression as the React element type. If you
>   do want to use a general expression to indicate the type of the
>   element, just assign it to a capitalized variable first. This often
>   comes up when you want to render a different component based on a
>   prop:

So you need to assign `this.props.onHex` to a CAPITALIZED variable first then you should be able to use it.

---

UPDATE again

Seems you want to pass a string, not a reference to the component. There is a dirty way to do that

```
const xxx = this.props.onHex || "";
const XxxComp = eval(xxx);
...
return (<XxxComp />);
```

I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/firice/pen/NvQrVW) for testing

Comment: It does not work by using `this.props.onHex` directly.

Comment: This likely wont work because it seems that OP is treating jsx as some sort of html extension and passing "component name" instead of a reference to the component.

Comment: @FiriceNguyen, ah right. You should point that out in your answer because as it currently stands, it doesn't really say what it solves.

Comment: @Chris: yeah, you are right. It's better to have some explanation. I have added more details :)

Comment: it not works for me, I tried `const XxxName = this.props.onHex;
      Xxx = <XxxName />;` not work, I tried `Xxx = <CustomComponent testInput={this.props.onHex}/>` same .. it creates <Unit> but not as component