# Refer to primitive DOM element class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

For example, I want to do this:

```
const DynamicComponent = condition ? MyComponent : React.div;

const usedDynamicComponent = <DynamicComponent> How cool? </DynamicComponent>;
```

What do I use there instead of `React.div`, which is a thing I just made up?

Comment: Check [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name#29876284) that seems to do the job

Comment: what are you aiming to achieve by using `React.div`? is it a simple `div` tag you want?

Comment: Yeah exactly @RaghavGarg

Answer (score 1):

```js
const DynamicComponent = condition ? MyComponent : <div>{this.props.children}</div>;

const usedDynamicComponent = <DynamicComponent> How cool? </DynamicComponent>;
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `this.props.children`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `this.props.children` to make a layout kind of thing. You can access the child of some component inside itself by using `this.props.children`.

```
class Div extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div {...this.props} >{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

This will wrap anything you put inside the `Div` tag between the HTML div tag. To access the props of the component given to the `<Div>`, you can simply add `{...this.props}`, it will add all your props on the actual `div`.

You can use the above-given component like:

```
<Div className="custom" custom_prop="value"><AnyReactComponent /></Div>
```

will convert to:

```
<div className="custom" custom_prop="value"><AnyReactComponent /></div>
```

Comment: That works but I was hoping it was possible to directly reference react's `div` class instead of wrapping it, which feels doesn't feel as elegant. But maybe this is the best we can do :)

Comment: Also this wouldn't pass any props passed to `Div` to the underlying div, like `className` for example.