# Dynamically name and nest components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically name some providers in react.  I am getting the following errors:

> The tag First.Provider is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant
>   to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

And

> First.Provider is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React
>   components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

I am not sure how to go about naming these components.  I have tried answers at the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name) but I am looping and nesting components so I need a beginning and ending tag so I don't think `React.createElement` will work and most of the answers in the above link are manually naming the component and I need to dynamically name the component corresponding to the value in an object.  Here is my code:

```
{Object.keys(state)
  .reverse()
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    const Tag = `${item}.Provider`;
    return <Tag>{acc}</Tag>;
  }, props.children)}
```

Comment: There are a variety of different approaches in duplicate link above

Comment: Looks like your `Tag` variable is just an interpolated string. The proper way would be something like this: `Tag = item[Provider]` to get the `Provider` value from the `item` object