# How to get a React component class from a string that contains the class name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6

**Note:** This question is not a duplicate of [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29875869/1175080). I am already aware of the solution used there in the accepted answer and if you read my question below, I am using a similar solution (using a map to convert a string to a component class) already. My question here is whether I can avoid maintaining such a map and convert the string directly to a component class.

Here is my code in `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Foo</h1>
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Bar</h1>
  }
}

function renderComponent(Component) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('root'))
}

function getComponent(name) {
  let map = {
    'Foo': Foo,
    'Bar': Bar,
  }
  return map[name]
}

renderComponent(getComponent('Foo'))
```

The `getComponent()` function takes a React component class name as a string input and returns the corresponding class?

Currently, I have an object literal in it to map each class name to a class? Everytime I add a new class, I have to update this object literal. Is there a way I can avoid maintaining this object literal?

Is there a way to write `getComponent()` in a manner that it can convert the class name as string input directly to a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Comment: Are you importing components from other files?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani No, I am not importing components from other files. You can see my source code in the question.

Comment: @skyboyer I am confused how the link you have mentioned answers my question. The answer there uses a `Components` map to look up the component class for a given string. Isn't that exactly what I am already doing here with the `map` object literal in my question?

Comment: *My question here is whether I can avoid maintaining such a map and convert the string directly to a component class.* - no, otherwise it would be suggested in dupe question. It is still a dupe.

Comment: fair enough, I should add something as a description. For just-a-gloabl-function you could get it through `window[dynamicFunctionName]` but for class it does not work. So there is no workaround. Keep using explicit mapping or refactor your app so you would not need instantiate component by name.