# Can a React component render another component stored in it's state?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to create a container component that might change its inner component over time.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { content: new FooComponent() }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            { this.state.content }
        </div>
    }
}
```

I get errors like:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I tried `{ [this.state.component] }`, but get same error.

Are you able to put components from `this.state` into the JSX that is returned from `render()`?  If not, how do you implement a container? I'm thinking of creating a container something like iOS's `UINavigationController`, where I can push and pop components in a stack, with only the top one rendered to the screen.

Comment: new will return an object (`this`) not the react component, use this: `content: <FooComponent />`, later will get converted into `content: React.createElement(FooComponent, .....)`, but storing react component in state is not a good idea, better to store the relevent info in state to render that component. Check [**MDN Doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), for more details about **how new operator works**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSX`: `this.state = { content: <FooComponent/> }`

Which is [React.createElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) behind the scenes.

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { content: <FooComponent/> }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.content}</div>;
    }
}
```

Or refer to [Creating React Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements).

For reference here are more readable forms:

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    content: <FooComponent />
  };

  render() {
    return <>{this.state.content}</>;
  }
}
```

```js
function Container() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(<FooComponent />);

  return <>{content}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can a React component render another component stored in it's state?

Yes you can!

There is two ways of doing it

1

```
import FooComponent from '..'

...
this.state = {
    content: <FooComponent/>
}
...
render(){
    return (
        <div>{this.state.content}</div>
    )
}
```

or

2

```
import FooComponent from '..'

...
this.state = {
    content: FooComponent
}
...
render(){
    const {
        content: BarComponent
    } = this.state

    return (
        <div>
            <BarComponent />
        </div>
    )
}
```

> I get errors like:
>
> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

- This happens because when you do `new FooComponent()` it returns an object and you can't render an object.
- When using JSX,  will be transpiled to `React.createElement(FooComponent)` and this is renderable.
- When using only `FooComponent`, you store a reference to it and only in the render method you create a JSX that will become `React.createElement(BarComponent)`

The second aproach is good when the component is comming from props and you depending on the situation, you want to give it some props.

Working [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/81r3yo0pv8)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Container extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { content: this.FooComponent() }
  }

 FooComponent(){
  return(<FooComponent/>)
 }

render() {
    return <div>
        { this.state.content }
    </div>
 }
}
```

Comment: you can render jsx or component by this way also

Answer (score 0):

The main question probably already answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name?rq=1).

Notice: Limited functionality - storing only components will be a simple stateless view/screen stack/buffer.

The problem can be much wider. This solution won't be equal to saving previous states, changes ... no props/params, no history, no context, state reversing ... but shared common state (redux store) can be an advantage - no old states, autoupdating the whole chain of stored views.