# Can I use a template literal inside a JSX tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I basically want to have variable components rendered inside a component I'm making which will vary depending on input provided by a user in the prop, but I want to avoid unnecessary `if` statements and so on.

Would I be able to do that? For example, if the `weather` prop is defined by the user as `Sun`, then `<{weather}/>` would be the same as `<Sun />`.

Comment: components need to start with a Capital letter, you can `const Component = weather;` and then use it as `<Component />`

Comment: Does this solve your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, names starting with a capital letter will compile to the createComponent method. So with that in mind, the correct solution is to assign the name value to a capitalized variable (see below).

```js
const WeatherComponent = props => {
  const ComponentTagName = props.weather;

  return <ComponentTagName />
}
```

Another technique I like to use is mapping child components in an object. This makes the component easier to configure (and reuse) as only an abbreviated key is required instead of the full component name.

```js
import React from 'react';

import SunComponent from './sun-component';
import RainComponent from './rain-component';


const WeatherComponents = {
     Sun: SunComponent,
     Rain: RainComponent
};

const WeatherComponent = (props) => {
    const TagName = WeatherComponents[props.weather || 'Sun'];
    return <TagName />
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really mix JSX syntax with template literals (although anywhere in JSX you could put `{a js expession}` you could use a template literal, you can't put an expression where a component name is expected).

But since `Sun` is just a variable with a value that is a component, if you were to call your prop `Weather` instead of `weather` you could: `<Weather />`

Answer (score 0):

If `weather` contains a reference to the `Sun` function, you can use `weather` directly (not via a template literal), but in lower case JSX will assume it's an HTML tag, not a component, and put it in quotes in the resulting `React.creatElement` call; so you have to use an initially-capped variable (`Weather` instead of `weather`):

```
<Weather />
```

If `weather` contains the **string** `"Sun"`, you can't directly use it to create a `Sun` element; you need a reference to the `Sun` function, not a string. You need a way to get from the string to the function (an object to look it up on, a `Map`, etc.).

---

You can use template literals elsewhere in JSX, within `{}`, since those contain JavaScript expressions. But not to define the component for a tag.