# How can I define an icon using template literals?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
 <Grid item>
          {attributesState.attributesData.socialPlatform.map((platform) => {
            <SocialButton
              isSelected={socialPlatform === platform.name}
              icon={<`${platform.name}Logo` />}
              onClick={() => {
                setSocialPlatform(SocialPlatform.BEHANCE);
              }}
            />;
          })}
```

I'm getting this error:

Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>'.ts(2322)
component.tsx(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'icon' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SocialButtonProps'
(JSX attribute) icon: React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a map/object to lookup the component you want actually rendered. In the mapping callback use the string template as a computed key into the lookup map/object, access the component value, and render.

[Choosing the type at runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
// ... import icon components

const icons = {
  icon1: Icon1Component,
  icon2: Icon2Component,
  .... etc...
};

...

{attributesState.attributesData.socialPlatform.map((platform) => {
  const IconComponent = icons[`${platform.name}Logo`];
  return (
    <SocialButton
      isSelected={socialPlatform === platform.name}
      icon={<IconComponent />}
      onClick={() => {
        setSocialPlatform(SocialPlatform.BEHANCE);
      }}
    />
  );
})}
```

Comment: I have the logo: 
import { ReactComponent as FacebookLogo } from '~/assets/img/icons/Facebook.svg';

The icons object: 
const icons = {
  Facebook: FacebookLogo,
};

And the component:
const IconComponent = icons[`${platform.name}`];
                return (
                  <SocialButton
                    isSelected={socialPlatform === platform.name}
                    icon={<IconComponent />}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSocialPlatform(platform.name);
                    }}
                  />
                );

Comment: And it gets the error: 

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Facebook: FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Facebook: FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>; }'

Comment: @Marinescu Are you certain what is supposed to be passed via this `icon` prop? It sort of seems like `SocialButton` is expecting a reference to a React components, not a JSX literal of it. Can you add what `SocialButton` is to your question?