# Return JSX elements that correspond to 1 or more keys in string array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-hooks

Looking for some help/guidance here. Maybe missing the obvious.
I am trying to build a component that takes either a `string or string Array string[]` as a property.

```
const ComponentThatReturnsElement = (someElementName) => {
   switch (someElementName) {
      case 'elementType1':
        return <>elementType1</>
      case 'elementType1':
         return <>elementType2</>
  }
}
```

The component then returns the corresponding element/s based on the string array. I am aware that a switchcase is not the ideal approach here or would even work. So looking for suggestions / ideas

The component I plan to call in another component in a map, example:

```
  {someArray.map(({ prop1, prop2 }) => (
                        <ComponentThatReturnsElement
                           key={prop1.someId}
                           elementType={prop2} // this can be be an array so I was thinking something like the below, again not sure.
                           elementType={prop2Array.map((data) => data.elementName}
                        />
                  ))}
```

basically im trying to feed an array of strings or string into a component that will dynamically return the corresponding elements based on the props passed to it from the map.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Comment: Not a react expert, but why do you need a component that returns an element, rather than a function that returns the element?

Comment: @Alan Well its a functional component, So I guess in this case its the same thing.

Comment: @PengProgrammer upon re-reading your example "ComponentThatReturnsElement" is not a valid React component, as it does not take a single argument "props". Instead you are passing in a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a normal funtion with returns JSX

```html
const functionThatReturnsElement = (someElementName) => {
   switch (someElementName) {
      case 'elementType1':
        return <ElementType1 />
      case 'elementType2':
         return <ElementType2 />
  }
}
```

then when mapping do like this

```html
  {someArray.map(({ prop1, prop2 }) => (
                        functionThatReturnsElement(prop1, prop2)
                  ))}
```