# How to use "react-icons" in loop (Map method) in ReactJS 

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I'm using **React-icons** in my **ReactJS** project and I just wanted to loop (by Map method) the **specific icons** in each **JSX** field when data is render.

In other word, I want this`` {`<${e.contact.icons}/>`} ``in **JSX** code.
Here is my code section:-

Here is, I **import** some **icons** for **React icons**.

```
import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FeAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Here is a data **array** which I want to render in **JSX**.

```js
const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'FaBeer',
      },
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'Fa500Px',
      },
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'FaAccusoft',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

And this is my component in down below. Which I'm using **icons**. You get little idea what I want to do.

```
const contact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="text-area">
              <span> {`<${e.contact.icons}/>`} </span>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default contact;
```

I'm trying to use like this`` {`<${e.contact.icons}/>`} ``, but is not working. When I see in browser. It's look like this.

```js
<FaBeer/>
<Fa500Px/>
<FaAccusoft/>
```

It's just return like a text, but I want to get **icons**.

```
Any suggestion ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the option of importing FaIcon-s and putting them into "data" array looks pretty nice:

```
import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa";

const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: FaBeer,
      },
...
```

On the other hand possibility of generating components "dynamically" by their string name could be still implemented.

Firstly, I find usefull following article: [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Next, I've created a new FaIconDynamic component:

```
import {
    AiFillAccountBook,
    AiFillAlert,
    AiFillAlipayCircle,
    AiFillAndroid,
} from 'react-icons/ai';

export const FaIconDynamic = ({ type }) => {
    const FaIcon = components[type];
    return <FaIcon></FaIcon>;
};

const components = {
    AiFillAccountBook,
    AiFillAlert,
    AiFillAlipayCircle,
    AiFillAndroid,
};
```

And then that's pretty easy to generate any registered above fa-icon, f.e.:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <FaIconDynamic type={'AiFillAccountBook'} />
            <FaIconDynamic type={'AiFillAlert'} />
            <FaIconDynamic type={'AiFillAlipayCircle'} />
            <FaIconDynamic type={'AiFillAndroid'} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Of course, both approaches have their pros and cons and could be more benefitial in some situations over each other

Comment: Your help is appreciable @Uladzimir. It looked like you did pretty well search on it.

Answer (score 4):

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-goldwasser-y83cn?file=/src/App.js

```
import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa";

// here is data for I want to show

const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: FaBeer
      },
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: Fa500Px
      },
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: FaAccusoft
      }
    ]
  }
];

const contact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            {e.contact.map((e, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="text-area" key={i}>
                  <h1 className="title">{e.title}</h1>
                  <h2 className="subtitle">{e.subtitle}</h2>
                  <span>
                    <e.icons />
                  </span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default contact;
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that `<e.icons/>` works as I thought that a [capitalized name](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) was a strict requirement.  Possibly it's ok because the actual value of `e.icons` is a component with a capitalized name?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use strings to represent React Component Types, instead you can use the imported `ComponentType` itself.

```js
import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa";

// here is data for I want to show

const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: FaBeer,
      },
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: Fa500Px,
      },
      {
        title: "contact",
        subtitle: "get in touch",
        icons: FaAccusoft,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e, i) => {
        const Icon = e.contact.icons;
        return (
          <>
            <div className="text-area">
              <h1 className="title">{e.contact.title}</h1>
              <h2 className="subtitle">{e.contact.subtitle}</h2>
              <span><Icon /></span>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Note how the rendering of the icon changes as well.  I have assigned the icon component to a variable `Icon` instead of calling `<e.contact.icons/>` directly because [React expects components to start with a capital letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

The `Icon` variable will be a React component (either a function component or a class component) so you can call that component by using standard JSX `<Icon />` syntax.  You can also pass any of the `react-icons` props, for example: `<Icon color="#FF0000" size={24}/>`.

Comment: @SanskarSahu Not sure what you mean

Comment: This is a good answer.  I edited it to provide a bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer. I know the answer is **not** an **ideal one,** but it's work for me just now. The **problem** with the **answer** is that. We imported **all** the **fonts** from react-icons. So, I guess, as we will grow the project **larger.**  It will **decrease the performances** and the major factor of could be **react icons.**
And also as Mr.**Ali Shefaee** describe in the comment section.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import * as FontAwesome from "react-icons/lib/fa";
```

Now that section we could use two type of method.

#### First one :-

Here we import the all **icons** and use the function to get **specific icon** which we want

```js
const Icon = props => {
  const { iconName, size, color } = props;
  const icon = React.createElement(FontAwesome[iconName]);
  return <div style={{ fontSize: size, color: color }}>{icon}</div>;
};
```

```js
const App = () => {
const iconString = "FaBeer";
  const beer = React.createElement(FontAwesome[iconString]); 
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon iconName={"FaBeer"} size={12} color="orange" />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

#### And Second :-

```js
  const App = () => {
  const iconString = "FaBeer";
  const beer = React.createElement(FontAwesome[iconString]);
  return (
    <div>
      <FontAwesome.FaBeer />
      <div style={{ fontSize: 24, color: "orange" }}>{beer}</div>
    </div>
  );
};


render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the Demo:- [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/o715x22m4z?file=/src/index.js:0-737).

Thank to〈Evie.Codes〉.

Comment: but this way do you think it is good for memory to import the whole ```FontAwesome``` package into this function scope? or it is better to import just required icons.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current answers already addresses the problem, so this only attempts to add small improvement for the solution. Here is an approach I tried in a similar situation.

Simplified demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-asbytl?file=src/App.js)

This will keep `data` the same as posted in the question as it might need to be fetched:

```
const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'FaBeer',
      },
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'Fa500Px',
      },
      {
        title: 'contact',
        icons: 'FaChrome',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Define an object with the imported icons as static data:

```
import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaChrome } from 'react-icons/fa';
const icons = { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaChrome };
```

In the output, the icon can taken out from static data, and rendered on condition:

```
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e, i) => (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          {e.contact.map((item, index) => {
            const Icon = icons?.[item.icons];
            return (
              <div key={index} className="text-area">
                <span>{Icon && <Icon size="3em" color="hotpink" />}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default contact;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Mr.@.John Li. But, it is a little modification. It not resolves the current issue. In your answer. We need to traverse the entire `icons?.[item.icons];` it's depending up on the `icons`. As you know, `icons` is the object which is the collection of few elements `{ FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaChrome };`. If I change in my `data` object and add some more icons or remove some icons. It will cause some error. The only option as I can see is to import all the icons from `react-icons/fa` but. It will decrease the performance when project grows large and not good for memory.

Answer (score 1):

> import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FeAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa";

**note:** there is a typo in the name of the icon you imported .. it should be ***FaAccusoft***

**my suggestion for your question** is to store the Icon components themselves in the object property  .. so instead of storing it as string: **"FaBeer"** ... store it as a component: **<FaBeer />** directly inside the object property .. like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    contact: [
      {
        title: "contact-1",
        icons: <FaBeer />
      },
      {
        title: "contact-2",
        icons: <Fa500Px />
      },
      {
        title: "contact-3",
        icons: <FaAccusoft />
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and then you can simply loop over them

```
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            {e.contact.map((c) => {
              return (
                <div className="text-area">
                  {c.title}
                  <span>
                    {c.icons} // you simply call it like this and the icon will be rendered
                  </span> 
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your help is appreciable @Raafat dev. But, the things are, I have no plan to make data static. It will be dynamic. I fetch from server, So, As you guess. Your answer is very obvious. I already try that but, it’s my helplessness to convert data into string. My question is only an example. As you know, the data is in array in object or JSON form. So, the most of the case, i not able to render elements as components.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Parser() from html-react-parser. https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser

```
const parse = require('html-react-parser');
{parse(`<${e.contact.icons}/>`)};
```

Comment: did you add - import { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaAccusoft } from "react-icons/fa"; in your file

Comment: yes, let me create https://codesandbox.io for you, give some time

Comment: the npm package has an issue with capital case elements,  { FaBeer, Fa500Px, FaAccusoft } https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser/issues/62
I can see in the browser the elements are parsed and rendered with lowercase like fabeer,fa500px,faaccusoft and browser does not recognize them. the lib says to add {      htmlparser2: { lowerCaseTags: false }          } option, but still it doesnot work according to git issue. ill see if there is any other lib  or fix for this