# When trying to return dynamic component, getting undefined error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to switch between components depending on passed prop. If `type === 'check'` - render `CheckList`, otherwise render `RadioList`. Both of these components accept same props. I tried following example given [here][1]. But when I tried running the code, I got error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
Check the render method of `List`.
```

My code in List.tsx is:

```
import CheckList from './Check/CheckList';
import RadioList from './Radio/RadioList';
import Props from './typings';

const list = {
  check: CheckList,
  radio: RadioList,
};

const List = ({type = 'radio', selected, options, callback}: Props) => {
  const ListType = list[type];

  return (
    <ListType list={options} selected={selected} callback={callback} />
  );
};

export default List;
```

When in `return` I replace `ListType` with either `RadioList` or `CheckList` - it works. I don't understand why it breaks when I use `ListType`. I checked all imports/exports and the fact that components work fine outside of `List` shows that they are not the problem.

I actually call for List inside RadioList component, so that it can return either radio list or check list for children:

```
import React from 'react';
import RadioButton from '../../../atoms/RadioButton/RadioButton';
import Props from './typings';
import {StyledSubcategory} from './styles';
import List from '../List';

const RadioList = ({list, selected, group, callback}: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {list.map((option, key) => (
        <>
          <RadioButton
            key={key}
            checked={false}
            label={option.label}
            value={option.value}
            callback={callback}
          />

          {option.sublist && (
            <StyledSubcategory $visible={true}>
              <List
                type={option.sublist.type}
                selected={false}
                options={option.sublist.options}
                callback={callback}
              />
            </StyledSubcategory>
          )}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default RadioList;
```

My props for `list` are:

```
const list = {
  type: 'radio',
  options: [
    {
      label: 'all',
      value: 'all',
    },
    {
      label: 'painting',
      value: 'painting',
      sublist: {
        type: 'radio',
        options: [
          {label: 'all', value: 'all'},
          {label: 'acrylic', value: 'type-acrylic'},
          {label: 'oil', value: 'type-oil'},
          {label: 'watercolour', value: 'type-watercolour'},
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

**UPDATE:**
I found what the issue was. My `list` object with my components was declared outside of my `List`, however once I brought it inside it worked:

```
import CheckList from './Check/CheckList';
import RadioList from './Radio/RadioList';
import Props from './typings';

const List = ({type = 'radio', selected, options, callback}: Props) => {
  const list = {
    check: CheckList,
    radio: RadioList,
  };
  const ListType = list[type];

  return (
    <ListType list={options} selected={selected} callback={callback} />
  );
};
```

Can someone explain why it's the case?
export default List;
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40896168/3629015

Comment: Can you try to wrap your component with `div` or `Fragment` and then return. It will work. In your case when it renders first time its returning nothing.

Comment: Just make sure you are exporting checklist and radiolist as a default export.
Check code-sandbox its working for me.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-darkness-m2lk99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried using both `<div>` and `React.Fragment`. Didn't work. I checked again all exports, they are in place.

Comment: Can you share `CheckList` or `RadioList` component. ?

Comment: Can you show us where do you use and pass props to the List component?

Comment: Qubaish Bhatti, CheckList isn't done yet - it accepts same props, but returns `<div></div>` at the moment.

Comment: If I use `switch` statement to switch between `type`s to return either `RadioList` or `CheckList` it works fine. But I really like how clean code is and I want to understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `type` property of the `List` component. You are passing `option.sublist.options` value to it, which is most probably undefined, and it overrides the default value `radio` as well.

Please make sure the value is not undefined, or pass it like so;

```
<List
   type={option?.sublist?.type ?? 'radio'}
   selected={false}
   options={option.sublist.options}
   callback={callback}
/>
```

Comment: But in List component I have a default value specified as `type = 'radio'`, so in case if it will be passed as `undefined`, it will change to `'radio'`