# mapping doesn't work inside react-router-dom's Routes component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

instead of type everything manually ,I just want to render my routes as an array.

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Home,
    layout: NonAuthLayout,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: About,
    layout: NonAuthLayout,
  },
];
```

and in my app.js file, I did something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((route, index) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            const Layout = route.layout || Fragment;
            return (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                element={
                  <Layout>
                    <Component />
                  </Layout>
                }
              />
            );
          })}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

But its giving error , while I tried to execute it.

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57985:5)
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12771:70)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12462:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12791:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57918:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56727:5)
    at App
    at SettingProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:174:5)
```

but but, If I put like this it works:

> <Route path="/" element={} />

**update- non-auth layout piucture**
[image: nonauth layout]

I think , I did some silly mistake. can someone correct me here?

Comment: How does `NonAuthLayout`,`Home`,`About`  looks like? Please share reproducible example

Comment: just made them using react snippet, nothing in there, I'm just providing the non-auth layout picture above.

Comment: Store the components like: `<Home/>` in your routes and not as `Home`. So you have `{ component: <Home/>, ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any overt issue with your code, and it in fact appears to run without issue.

[image: Edit mapping-doesnt-work-inside-react-router-doms-routes-component]

I suspect you may have a component export/import issue with one or more of the `Home`, `About`, and `NonAuthLayout` components, so double check these.

### But, there's a simpler way

Don't re-invent the wheel. `react-router-dom` exports a [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook that effectively does this.

Reconfigure your routes config to comply with the RRD syntax:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    element: <NonAuthLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

NonAuthLayout

`NonAuthLayout` is now a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) and needs to render an `Outlet` instead of a `children` prop.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NonAuthLayout = () => (
  <Box>
    <div>
     <TopBar />
    </div>
    <Box>
      <Outlet />
    </Box>
  </Box>
);
```

App

```
import { BrowserRouter, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from '../path/to/routes';

...

const element = useRoutes(routes);

...

<BrowserRouter>
  {element}
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit mapping-doesnt-work-inside-react-router-doms-routes-component (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to render components using a dynamic component name like in this solution:

[React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

It doesn't work because when you do `const Component = route.component` you are just getting the string (e.g. "Home" or "About")

Your variable needs to hold a reference to **the component itself**, not just the **name of the component as a string**

So, store your components in an array and render from it using the dynamic variable name returned from `route.component`

Something along the lines of:

```
import HomeComponent from './components/home'
import AboutComponent from './components/about'

const components = {
  home: HomeComponent,
  about: AboutComponent
}

const Component = components[route.component];
```

It's a bit of work to give the correct solution without seeing more of your code, but the concept (and your error) is quite fundamental, so it's best that you refer to both the post I linked above, and the official React docs here to understand this better:

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime

Comment: thank for posting this, learned a new thing today, but sorry mate its not what i'm looking