# How to Change tag name in react js with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have a code like this
I want to change the tag name starting with <all.

```
{services.map((item) => (
        <div className="space-x-[8px] py-[8px] flex ">
        <div className="flex flex-col text-center relative px-[8px] py-[8px] items-center active:bg-[#f5f5f5]  cursor-pointer">
          <All.${item}
            sx={{ fontSize: "40px" }}
            className="text-[#6B84DD] w-[64px] h-[p64x] text-3xl"
          />
          <span className=" font-merrisans text-[14px] font-semibold">
            {item}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      ))}
```

I tried like this

```
{services.map((item) => (
        <div className="space-x-[8px] py-[8px] flex ">
        <div className="flex flex-col text-center relative px-[8px] py-[8px] items-center active:bg-[#f5f5f5]  cursor-pointer">
          {(`{<All.${item}
            sx={{ fontSize: "40px" }}
            className="text-[#6B84DD] w-[64px] h-[p64x] text-3xl"
          />`)}
          <span className=" font-merrisans text-[14px] font-semibold">
            {item}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      ))}
```

but it didn't worked
it showing
[image]

Comment: Which attribute?

Comment: {(`{<All.${item}

Comment: I want to render different components. but it renders html of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name

Comment: Btw, `it's a tag name, not an attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#anatomy_of_an_html_element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#attributes

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not a string, you can't use `${}`

```
{
  services.map((item) => {
    const Component = All[item];
    return (
      <div className="space-x-[8px] py-[8px] flex ">
        <div className="flex flex-col text-center relative px-[8px] py-[8px] items-center active:bg-[#f5f5f5]  cursor-pointer">
          <Component
            sx={{ fontSize: "40px" }}
            className="text-[#6B84DD] w-[64px] h-[p64x] text-3xl"
          />
          <span className=" font-merrisans text-[14px] font-semibold">
            {item}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: It is showing.....    The tag <Carpenter> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @ShashankSingh you didn't really show what is `All`. Seems like `All.something` is not a react component but a string

Comment: Actually I imported some icons from a js file as All. that's why i am using All.item. but even now i have imported them singularly. It is treating Component as a String not referencing to the actual imported icon.