React - convert a string to a component name - problem
Hi I work on some improvments and I came across some issue with changing string with name of my icon component to lower case which generate a error becuasue icons are not showed :/
Everything works before fine because I passed original name of components in the right places.
code of function with problem:
function generateIconComponent(IconName: string): JSX.Element {
  return(
    <>
      <div id='iconComponent'>
        <IconName size='56' />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

At the picture after run of code in marked place should be "Binoculars" instead "binoculars".
Also I cant use another additional outer libs to achieve this goal!!!
error
I looked for answer on forum and I found https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name&ved=2ahUKEwjl0qW-pKaGAxV_JBAIHdE2DvoQFnoECCMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2k4vouwBkA8S324WfJfDI9
but it wasn't helpful.

In order to achieve this, you would need a mapping, to map a key to an icon.
For example:
const iconMapping = {
  'Binoculars': Binoculars, // this is the actual icon
};

and then your generateIconComponent can be changed to:
function generateIconComponent(IconName: string): JSX.Element {
  // Use the passed string to select the appropriate component from the mapping
  const IconComponent = iconMapping[IconName];

  return (
    <div id='iconComponent'>
      <IconComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

